# Cron job with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron, server

I am developing a Cron application using Laravel 4.2.11. I used below command as Cron command.

```
wget http://apiproducts.com/foysal/public/get_products
```

Where `get_products` is a route defined in *routes.php*.

But this command generates .txt file in server,like *get_products.txt, get_products.1.txt, get_products.2.txt* etc.

How can I get rid of this issue??

Comment: What issue? What do you expect to happen? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks @Jite for your response. I would like to stop .txt file generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is a tool to retrieve something from the net (download), not just to send requests:

> GNU Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP, the most widely-used Internet protocols.

So, when calling this command, without any options, you will get the file with the response.

If you are only after the ability to send a request, and you don't intend to fetch the page, you should probably rather look at [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), which allows you to send requests via the terminal, and would work fine in a cron-job.

Your command would be changed to look like:

```
curl http://apiproducts.com/foysal/public/get_products
```

Comment: Thanks @Jite. Your solution is working.I have another question. Is `sleep()` of php problematic for  CRON ??

Comment: Cron will run the script/job when its set to run it. It should not care how the code looks. So if you for some reason have to use `sleep` in your code, it should be fine. If you have any issues with it, id recommend posting a new question. :)